# Does careless voting or non-voting damage this site?

Tags: discussion

Looking at [this months voters](https://german.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters&filter=month) we can see that from at present 731 visits/day we only had 14 users who contribute by voting.

Here are my guesses why this may be so:

- significant shortage of questions we have
- many active users seem to have disappeared recently

In addition we can see another possibly more worrysome find in the montly voters overview. We now for the first time have **avid users** who do not gain but **lose reputation**. I am not (yet) amongst them but still I may be affected as from my last 10 answers 7 were downvoted (for reasons obscure to me).

> **This makes me believe that there is someting badly wrong with our voting attitude.**

What could be done to improve this?

Comment: When you say "we" you don't mean yourself and me, right? http://german.stackexchange.com/badges/44/electorate?userid=44 ;-)

Comment: @splattne: lol - I was wondering for a long time why nobody wants this ;)

Comment: My statement: We currently do have too much crap but rarely good questions and answers. Bummer.

Answer (score 7):

### Yes it damages our site

These are my recent posts that were downvoted as *"crap"* as a user put it here in a [comment](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/422/does-careless-voting-or-non-voting-damage-this-site#comment987_422):

- [Expressions to congratulate on October the 3rd (Day of German Unity)](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5278/expressions-to-congratulate-on-october-the-3rd-day-of-german-unity/5281#5281)
- https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5235/is-there-a-word-waltzmarsch-in-german/5238#5238
- [Suche ein Wort, in Richtung: Periode, Zyklus, Progression, Staffel, Tagebuch usw.](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5217/suche-ein-wort-in-richtung-periode-zyklus-progression-staffel-tagebuch-usw/5220#5220)
- [Prägnante Übersetzung von engl. "views" (wie in "42 views of this post")](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5169/pragnante-ubersetzung-von-engl-views-wie-in-42-views-of-this-post/5172#5172)
- [Plural of Assembly](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5149/plural-of-assembly/5152#5152)
- [Beziehung zwischen dem Warten von Maschinen und dem Warten auf ein Ereignis?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5130/beziehung-zwischen-dem-warten-von-maschinen-und-dem-warten-auf-ein-ereignis/5132#5132)
- [Unterschied zwischen "Klamotten" und "Kleider"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5108/unterschied-zwischen-klamotten-und-kleider/5111#5111)
- [How is “Parameter” pronounced?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4934/how-is-parameter-pronounced/4935#4935)
- [Weniger informeller Ausdruck für "weg-abstrahieren"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4910/weniger-informeller-ausdruck-fur-weg-abstrahieren/4915#4915)
- [When to use "spendieren" rather than "spenden"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5246/when-to-use-spendieren-rather-than-spenden)
- [Wo leitet sich das verstärkende Präfix "stink-" her?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5232/wo-leitet-sich-das-verstarkende-prafix-stink-her)

People know that when I write an answer I do take my time for research. Mostly I try to find a reliable reference before I answer. Only rarely I communicate my own personally biased opinion when there are hard facts. For me a down-vote shows disrespect for my efforts. Therefore, [I do vote for questions that are interesting, I do vote for answers that are correct](https://german.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters&filter=all). I vote because I know how much time it took to write them.

**I do not see much poor content here. But I see people answer less and less, comment more and more, forget to also vote on the question, and I also see people having a worrisome lack of tolerance for other people's opinions.**

Yes, I can see that some posts are in large parts off-topic, over-lengthy, or they only partly answer the question. I don't up-vote them because in my opinion they are not really good but I can live with them. They are not poor either. I would never get the idea to down-vote them. Sometimes however - I admit - I can't understand why these posts get so many up-votes.

Speaking for myself, I am not prepared to spend my time struggling to contribute when there is not much more feedback than an unexplained downvote here an there. It both annoys me, and makes me sad. **It is not what I came here for.**

If only a few of the once so avid users we had who now had turned the back to this site felt the same then

### Yes, it damages the site

We should do something about it.

Comment: Wenn ich von "crap" rede, meine ich vor allen Dingen die Ratespiele, die wir kürzlichst hatten. - Einige der Downvotes die du da gelistet hast, waren von mir. Ich erwarte nicht, dass du die Downvotes verstehst, weil genauso wenig verstehe ich manche Downvotes, die ich verpasst bekomme. Der Aufwand, der dahinter steckt, kenne ich - du weißt, dass ich auch schon mal in Wortgeschwafel verfalle. Aber genau da riskiert man halt irgendwo etwas zu sagen, was einem nicht passt. Und obwohl 99% stimmt, ein Satz vermasselt es manchmal. Damit müssen wir beide leben. - Auch wenn ich mich immer freue, ...

Comment: ... wenn meine Antworten upgevoted oder gar akzeptiert werden, störe ich mich nicht daran, wenn meine Frage am Ende auf +-0 ankommt. Du solltest es auch nicht so persönlich sehen. - Anderes Ding, mich erschreckt es eigenltich wieviel du upvotest. Mir ist bewusst, dass ich da auch schon den ein oder anderen upvote von dir bekommen habe, den ich eigentlich gar nicht verdient hatte; aber - und das siehst du auch an meinen oft vllt etwas zu harschen Kommentaren - ich sehe nicht alles so positiv wie du. Und da werde ich meine Meinung auch nicht ändern. Hat aber auch einen bestimmten Grund. .....

Comment: Du hast eine zeitlang mit deinen Fragen, den Schnitt höher gehalten, als er wirklich ist. Auf der einen Seite ist das nützlich, auf der anderen Seite entsteht aber auch eine Abhängigkeit. Wie stark die Fragerate gefallen ist, sieht man ja. - Was ich nur sagen will, man darf das pushen auch nicht übertreiben; es bringt nichts, etwas zu simulieren, was gar nicht da ist; es bricht zwangsweise irgendwann zusammen. - Ich sehe ehrlich gesagt keinen Schaden, weder kürzlichst, noch innerhalb des halben Jahres wo ich jetzt hier war.

Comment: Ach, fällt mir gerade beim Lesen auf... Wenn ich im ersten Kommentar sage, dass man bei viel Geschwafel schon mal einen falschen Satz sagt, heißt das nicht, dass das meine Downvote-Gründe für deine Antworten waren. - Hauptsächlich sind die Gründe wirklich "not useful"; und meist hab ich es kommentiert (wobei ich nicht immer downvote, wenn ich negativ kommentiere; sondern nur dann, wenn ich mit der grundsätzlichen Aussage nicht übereinstimme - verzwickt; aber zum Beispiel beim Waltzmarsch habe ich genau deine Antwort als einzige nicht downgevotet, da zumindest die Argumentation stimmte)

Comment: @Em1 Meiner Meinung nach ist „wenn ich mit der grundsätzlichen Aussage nicht übereinstimme“ kein ausreichender Grund für einen Downvote. Die FAQ _aller_ Stackexchange-Seiten raten „Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.“ Allerdings bin ich zu selten auf GL&U, um beurteilen zu können, wie das hier im allgemeinen gehandhabt wird. Gibt es Hausregeln (wie z.B. auf TeX.sx)?

Comment: @Clemens Das stimmt. Daher downvote ich auch nicht jede Frage, wo ich die Aussage als falsch ansehe. Manchmal weiß ich es auch nicht besser und belasse es daher bei "gar kein Vote". Als ich diese Aussage geschrieben habe, habe ich im Wesentlichen an Antworten gedacht, die offensichtlich eine Vielzahl an Fehlern aufweist und daher meines Erachtens nicht hilfreich ist.

Comment: @Em1 Ah ok, dann hab ich Deinen Kommentar missverstanden.

Answer (score 3):

I second that and want to add that I find this to be true for careleess *up*-voting as well. For example [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5293/ist-schwer-zu-angelnder-eine-zulassige-satzkonstruktion), the first answer wasn't an answer at all, but rather an opinion and received three upvotes – one upvote more than my question itself. This would be better put in a comment and not as an answer (where one can use upvotes to agree, too). I feel simiarly with other answers: They are subjective and more comments than answers, yet they get upvoted.

However, I also do downvote (twice or thrice so far), sometimes appreciate comments over answers (as mentioned above) and I'm looking for more definite and objective answers than just mere opinions. So I wonder if fall into your description. Therefore I want to also say that I do explain my downvotes and have reasons to mistrust subjective answers.

I also regret that many active users seem to have left, which must have been before I came on board. (Is, … is this site going downhill?)

Comment: Answer noted, thank you. Do carry on with the good work you presented here so far!

Answer (score 2):

The link only shows you the people who had more than 10 votes in the indicated period. In particular, search engine drivers who just look at one question will never be counted even if they live a couple of upvotes there.

Also, the fact that some users don't have the electorate badge doesn't mean that they didn't vote more than 600 times.

Comment: I just looked it up, I *should* have the electorate badge.

Comment: Me too. 957 total, 284 on questions.

Comment: You need at least 600 votes on _questions_ (plus at least 25% of total votes on questions). Since you both have less than 400 on questions => no badge

Answer (score 2):

I'm new here and when I wrote my first two or three answers I was downvoted by only one special user on a downvoting tour. That causes me to flag the bad votings of this user and I was so angry that I thaught I can vaste my time in a better way. I don't know the english words/phrase, so German: Ich dachte wirklich, ich wäre im falschen Film.

Next day I wasn't so angry further more and returned to this side, but this user continued with bad and wrong comments. In one case I wrote some heavy comments to shut him up.

This kind of behavior specialy of this user, but also generaly, is not good for this side and I think there is a great need to fix this. First with telling to be kind and friendly with acurate and complete comments, questions and answers. If this does not help at last throw him out.

I think downvoting is only useful if something is completly wrong (in a bad way). Only downvoting because the question or answer gives not the own opinion is real bad behavior. And does never support this side.

I'm new here so I first take a look around to see how the voting runs here. Til today I can't see rules for the too much downvoting here. Thats the reason you will not see a lot of upvotes from me.

Comment: Ohne jetzt deine Sichtweise entgegnen zu wollen, aber ich weiß, dass öfters negativ über diesen User hier und dort gesprochen wird. Man muss diesem User aber zu Gute halten, dass er nahezu immer einen Kommentar hinterlässt. Ich finde beide Downvotes von ihm (zu deinen Antworten) etwas zu harsch (beide sind imho weder up- noch downvotebar), dennoch sehe ich das Problem, dass hier auf der anderen Seite viel zu viel upgevoted wird. Somit sollte sich niemand darüber beschweren, dass hier 1 oder 2 User sind, die eben gegen den Strom schwimmen und nicht alles mit einer rosa-roten Brille sehe.

Comment: Ergänzend: Hier sind einige User, die leider nicht mit negativer Kritik umgehen können. Das Kommentare von diesem User, aber auch meine, manchmal etwas zu harsch ausfallen, ist vielleicht nicht hilfreich, aber zu argumentieren, solche User rauszuschmeißen, ist genau so falsch. Es gibt einige User hier, mit denen ich nicht zu recht komme, aber ich ignoriere diese einfach, flagge Kommentare, wenn sie direkt an mich gerichtet sind und lache über die indirekten Sticheleien. - Aber das nur mal so am Rande.

Comment: @Em1: Tatsächlich sehe ich das Rausschmeißen als letzte Möglichkeit, und ich habe ja auch geschrieben, vorher mit ihm zu reden. Ich habe keinen Einblick darüber, wie viele User hier sind/voten/aktiv sind, aber ich bin mir sicher, dass es viele gibt, die durch eine solche ungerechtfertigte Downvote-Tour mit Recht abgeschreckt werden, hier noch Zeit zu investieren. Und das schadet der Seite hier. Da hilft es dann auch nicht einen unwahren und halblebigen Kommentar hinzurotzen (sorry für diese Wortwahl, aber das triffts am besten). Diese Seite lebt vom **Mitmachen**, aber bestimmt nicht vom

Comment: @Em1: **verunglimpfen** oder **niedermachen** von anderen zum Zwecke der eigenen Profilierung. Ich vermute ein grottenfalsches Selbstbildnis in solchen Fällen und liege nur sehr selten daneben. Und jemanden nur deshalb herabzustufen, weil dessen Sichtweise nicht zur eigenen passt, zeigt nur das mässige Niveau des Downvoters und dessen mangelnde Weitsicht oder Bereitschaft, auch mal andere Standpunkte zu **prüfen** und ggf. zu übernehmen. Ganz ehrlich: so ein Verhalten erwarte ich bei einem sechjährigen Kind und kann es da auch verstehen und nachvollziehen, absolut nicht bei einem Erwachsenen.

Comment: @Em1: konstruktive, sachliche und wohlbegründete Kritik ist wertvoll, hilfreich und wünschenswert. Damit sollte jeder umgehen können (spätestens wenn er eine wissenschaftliche Ausbildung durchlaufen hat). Negative Kritik (nur jetzt spreche ich von negativ!), die nur einem "Platzhirschverhalten" oder dem Selbstverständis "§1: User X hat immer recht. §2: Sollte User X einmal nicht recht haben, tritt automatisch §1 in Kraft" entspringt ist hier absolut fehl am Platz. **Harsche** oder **beleidigende** Kritik ist ebenfalls Fehl am Platz. Ändert sich das nicht, verliert die Seite immer mehr User.

Comment: @Em1: Ganz besonders erschreckend finde ich, dass sich (aus meiner Sicht) wohlverdiente User wie Takkat eine Auszeitnehmen müssen (siehe Chat). Hier stehen die Zeichen auf Alarmstufe **Rot**!

Comment: Ich find es aber übertrieben, was hier seit 1-2 Monaten rumgeheult wird. Wenn ich so empfindlich reagieren würde, müsste ich ständig auf ELU einen Metaeintrag verfassen, warum denn schon wieder irgendwer grundlos irgendwas downvoted oder so. [Das hier](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2703/16833) sind ernsthafte Probleme, nicht die paar Downvotes, die hier der ein oder andere User verteilt.

Comment: @Em1: Na schön, das findest **Du** übertrieben. Bist Du **alle**? Oder tritt jetzt automatisch Paragraf 2 in Kraft? (Sorry für die Polemik, aber ist jetzt klar, was ich meine?) Meine Reaktion und die vieler anderer hat nichts mit Empfindlichkeit zu tun, eher mit Sprachgefühl und einem wachen Sinn für sprechende Nuancen. Wenn auf ELU Alphatierchen ihre Machtkämpfe austragen wollen, sollen sie es dort tun und nicht hier. Hier geht es um einen gepflegten, facettenreichen Umgang mit der deutschen Sprache, nicht um Alphatier-Machtkämpfe. Von dem Mist haben wir schon in der Politik genug davon.

Comment: @Em1: Eine weitere Diskussion besser im Chat?

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, ob eine Diskussion im Chat viel dazu beiträgt. Ich will nur eines noch sagen. Ich vertrete nicht die Meinung aller, habe ich ja nie gesagt. Ich sage *ich* finde es übertrieben. Und ich vertrete wohlbemerkt eine entgegensätzliche Meinung zu vielen. Ich bin ja sowieso beinahe alleine. Aber das heißt ja nicht, dass ich nicht diese Position darstellen sollte. Und mein Standpunkt ist "Es ist übertrieben". Also sage ich das.

Comment: @Em1: Warum nicht? Gerade eine ehrliche Diskussion kann auch Standpunkte verrücken. Nicht zu diskutieren heißt zu verharren. Und wenn Du schon weißt, dass Du relativ alleine mit deinem Standpunkt da stehst, mußt Du dann Deinen Standpunkt überall **durchdrücken** (Meines Wissens nennt man das rechthaberisch ... Fasst man das Ganze etwas böser auf, kann man auch "terrorisieren" [passt zu User X] sagen), sei es durch Downvoting oder Kommentare, wenn doch nahezu alle **nicht** Deiner Meinung sind? Und je höher die Reputation ist desto sorgfältiger sollte man mit seinen Äußerungen umgehen ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6150/discussion-between-em1-and-kurt)

Comment: Kleine Information am Rande: Downvotes auf Meta bedeuten 'ich bin dagegen' oder 'ich stimme nicht zu'. Das ist nicht meine persönliche Ansicht, sondern die offizielle Sichtweise. Desweiteren sagen die Tooltiptexte, was Pfeil auf/ab bedeutet. Die Diskussion hatten wir aber auch schon auf Meta. Wenn Du Grund siehst einen speziellen Kommentar debattieren zu wollen, dann musst Du schon sagen welchen. Ein vages Kritisieren im Allgemeinen ist leicht und unfair - wie soll man sich dagegen verteidigen? Wo beispielsweise habe ich einen unwahren Kommentar hinterlassen?

Comment: Ich lege auch Wert auf die Feststellung, dass ein Downvote nicht ein Abwerten der Person ist, die einen Text verfasst hat, sondern ein Abwerten des Textes alleine. Ich habe hier noch keine Person abgewertet und habe es auch in Zukunft nicht vor. Ich bitte Dich die Wertungen nicht persönlich zu nehmen - damit tust Du ihnen Unrecht. Bedenke, dass es andere Personen jederzeit die Möglichkeit haben die Votings zu kompensieren, wenn sie der Ansicht sind, sie hätten es verdient. Du musst nicht jeden überzeugen - die Mehrheit sollte Dir genügen.

Comment: The problem especially with "German language and usage" is that there are too many people answering without being a real linguist. This leads to many wrong answers. Next thing is that many non-Germans upvote those answers because they suppose that may be the right answer. So it's no wonder that downvoting happens from time to time... Unfortunately, it's a systematic problem with that site.